# Can I access another app from my app?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7

I want to write an app for Windows Phone (although I dont think it matters for my question.)
I was wondering if I can "connect " to an existing app in my app to get information from there.
for example- lets say I want to develop an app that keeps all your scores from the games you have on your phone.
Can I ,in my app, somehow get an access to other apps information? (AngryBirds's scores and etc...) so I can display it on my app?
(but even more than scores- lets say my app will open another app and search something in that app and then will use the data... )
I was looking on the web for an answer and couldnt find...
Hopefully my question is clear.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I ,in my app, somehow get an access to other apps information?

Only if the other app provides some sort of API for it. Most do not.